# GlassFish v3.1 preventing several users login with same credentials

Tags: security, authentication, glassfish, credentials

I am daveloping a JSF application that uses the GlassFish Security Realms for authentication. Everything works fine, but I am facing one problem though. Several users may login with the same credentials at a time.

So: How do I prevent logging in if a user with the same credentials is already logged ?
(lets say I have 3 users that share the same credentials, but I want only one to be able to login at a time)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the implementation of the authentication but in general you'll have to keep a "logged in" flag somewhere (e.g. in the user db) and set/check that flag on every login attempt. Furthermore you'll have to set the flag back to false if a user logs out.

Comment: All authentication and authorisation is handled by Glassfish so I am looking for some GFish configuration thing. I could do what you wrote but how do I tell GFish to check that ?

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own [ServerAuthModule](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gizdx/index.html). An example implementation can be found on the next page. Additional information e.g. [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/adding_authentication_mechanisms_to_the)